# Accessing nested JSON data from axios response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, airtable

I am not able to access response data. Here's what I've done:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function AddFishingTrip() {
    let [pierName, setPierName] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/').then((response) => {
            setPierName(response.data);
          });
    },[]);
    console.log(pierName);
    return (<div>{pierName && pierName.map((i) => <p>{i.fields.name}</p>)}</div>);
```

I am getting response data with axios, but I am not able to access it. Here is a photo of the response data.

[image: response data]

I have tried the following to access the name of the piers and a bunch of other weird combinations:

`pierName.records[0].fields.name`,
`pierName[0].fields.name`

What am I not understanding?

I get an error when I try to map pierName that would indicate that it isn't an array. `pierName.map is not a function`. I'm missing some sort of critical concept.

Comment: are you able to setup here - `setPierName(response.data);`

Comment: @SonuSindhu I don't understand your question? It works. I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, replace the code where you're mapping the json to render it inside the paragraph tag like this:

```
return (<div>{pierName && pierName.map((i) => <p>{i.fields.name}</p>)}</div>);
```